# Better to ReDim array multiple times or reopen recordset?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, recordset

I'm writing code in VBscript that opens a recordset object and then loads an array with objects containing data from each record. My recordset type doesn't support the `rs.RecordCount` property, so I either need to `ReDim Preserve` the array while looping through the recordset or I need to reopen the recordset after doing a counting loop, since using `rs.MoveFirst` after the counting loop doesn't seem to work... Which would be faster? There is only at most 7 records in the recordset object, so at most I would need to ReDim that many times.

This is one way I attempted, but rs.MoveFirst doesn't seem to work correctly, see comments:

```
Function LoadData(filter_val)
   Dim arr
   Dim rs
   'Calls function that opens the rs and returns it
   Set rs = GetRS(filter_val)

   Dim counter
   counter = 0
   Do Until rs.EOF
      counter = counter + 1
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop

   ReDim arr(counter)

   rs.MoveFirst

   For i = 0 To counter
      Set arr(i) = New obj
      'attempt to load values into the object from the recordset, but get an
      'error saying 'either BOF or EOF is true, or the current record has been deleted'
      'I tried adding If statements with MsgBox print outs checking for rs.EOF or rs.BOF
      'being true right after rs.MoveFirst, but neither evaluates to true...
   Next
End Function
```

This method works, but I have to continuously ReDim the array:

```
Function LoadData(filter_val)
   Dim arr
   Dim rs
   Set rs = GetRS(filter_val)

   Dim counter
   counter = 0
   ReDim arr(counter)

   Do Until rs.EOF
      Set arr(counter) = New obj

      'load data from rs into object

      rs.MoveNext

      If Not rs.EOF
         counter = counter + 1
         ReDim Preserve arr(counter)
      End If

   Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Your first method will resize the array to be one larger than the size of the record set. Is that what you want? That might be why you're reaching EOF before you expect to. Either set `counter=-1` or `ReDim arr(counter-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-dimensioning arrays performs surprisingly well, so I'd go with `ReDim`. The generic way to increase the size of an array is to initialize it as an empty array:

```
ReDim arr(-1)
```

and then increase the upper boundary by one with every iteration before adding something:

```
Do Until rs.EOF
  ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr)+1)
  Set arr(UBound(arr)) = New obj

  'load data from rs into object

  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

That way you don't need a counter variable for keeping track of the array size.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll go with this. For my own learning, could you point me to a resource that explains why Re-dimensioning performs well? I'm no computer scientist, but my intuition tells me that `ReDim Preserve` would be a costly operation, especially if that array elements are custom class objects that hold a lot of data. Does it not need to reload the whole array, and just allocates more memory for an extra array element or something?

Comment: I can't explain why it performs so well. I would've expected the opposite, since `ReDim Preserve` re-creates the array and copies all existing elements (AFAIK that is). However, benchmarking `ReDim Preserve`, `Scripting.Dictionary` and `System.Collections.ArrayList` with a couple hundred thousend elements proved otherwise.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Interesting! Always more to learn.

Answer (score -1):

This appears easier, from  MSDN

> **GetRows Method (ADO)**
>
> Retrieves multiple records of a Recordset object into an array.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ---
>
> `array = recordset.GetRows(Rows, Start, Fields )`
>
> **Return Value**
>
> ---
>
> Returns a Variant whose value is a two-dimensional array.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ---
>
> **Rows** 
>   Optional. A GetRowsOptionEnum value that indicates the number of records to retrieve. The default is adGetRowsRest.
>    **Start** 
>   Optional. A String value or Variant that evaluates to the bookmark for the record from which the GetRows operation should begin. You can also use a BookmarkEnum value.
>    **Fields** 
>   Optional. A Variant that represents a single field name or ordinal position, or an array of field names or ordinal position numbers. ADO returns only the data in these fields.

---

Also just dim the array to 7 if the max is 7.

Comment: I did suggest this in the comments but quickly realised the OP is storing the `ADO.Recordset` record in a custom class `New obj` *(1D Array)*. So removed my comment.